# cheeriojs - How to loop through every object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scrape, cheerio

I have this code below:

```
$('.name').filter(function(){
    var data = $(this);
    name = data.text();

    json.name = name;
})
```

This will return the text from this div:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="name">This is a name</a>
```

Basically on the page there around 20 photos of people, so there are around 20 or so `<a>` tags on the page with a class name of `name`. How would I loop through each `<a>` tag and produce a JSON variable which would contain something like this below

```
{ [id: 0, name: 'name 1'],[id: 1, name: 'name 2'] }
```

At the moment I can only get it to hold the value of one name, which is useless to me at the moment!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have jQuery available, that eases the task a little bit. Using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var myList = [];
var id = 0;
$('name').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).text();
  myList.push({id: id, name: name});
  id = id + 1;
}
console.log(myList);
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble making this into JSON which I can write as an output, can you help me out with that? Before I was outputting the JSON as this: `fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4)` But now I am dealing with an array, and I cannot seem to get the myList to output successfully to the JSON output.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myList);` shall work. I ran the following example in console: `$ node -e "var a = [{id: 1, name: 'name 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'name 2'}]; console.log(JSON.stringify(a));"
[{"id":1,"name":"name 1"},{"id":2,"name":"name 2"}]
`